# Duplicated icons at the top

Tags: 22.04

Does anyone know how to remove these duplicated icons at the top of the screen (on Ubuntu 22.04?)

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXl3x.png)

Answer (score 2):

These icons are provided by Gnome Shell extensions. Different extensions can provide this functionality, so the possibility exists you are running two different extensions that do that. One is "Ubuntu Appindicators" and is installed by default. Thus, check the extensions you have installed, and see whether there is another also running, which you then should disable.

Install the tool Extensions (`sudo apt gnome-shell-extension-prefs`) to manage manually installed and build-in gnome shell extensions.